# Create a view in Django that adds one record to a M2M relationship without a form

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm trying to create a simple view that adds an instance of a model to a different model without a form.

Background:
I can't use the multi-select widget because IOS7's multi-select on the iPhone is broken. So I'm creating a workaround will actually be a better experience in the long run anyway.

I want a view that accepts two PKs. It updates the parent model with an instance of the child model via M2M. But I want to do it WITHOUT a form.

Here's what I have so far:

URL: `url(regex=r'^attt/(?P<parent_id>\d+)/(?P<child_id>\d+)/$', view=addChildToParent, name='add_child_to_the_parent',),`

View:

```
def addChildToParent(request, parent_id, child_id):
    """
    This view is about adding children to the parent.
    """

    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)

    if request.user != user:
        return permission_denied(request)

    try:
        parent = Parent.objects.get(id=request.parent_id)
        child = Child.objects.get(id=request.child_id)
        parent.parent_children.add(child)
        messages.success(self.request, "Your child was added!")
        return redirect('parent_overview', pk=parent.id)

    except Parent.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

Error:

`addChildToParent() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parent_id'`

After reading the docs, it seems like `add()` is what I'm supposed to do to update the m2m between Parent and Child with a new Child. But it's not working. The actual `add()` isn't happening.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I feel so silly. You just need `save()` to save teh relationship and update the record.

Answer (score 0):

When you have named groups in your url definition, they are passed as keyword arguments to the view. If you rename your view as such, it should work:

```
def addChildToParent(request, parent_id, child_id):
```

You can then refer to those parameters directly.

Comment: You're right. That was missing. Updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.save()` method to save the actual relationship.